# I can not remove the "bad" disk from the zfs pool

Tags: zfs

1. There were 2 disks in the pool /dev/sde /dev/sdf
2. The disk  /dev/sde was damaged, I excluded it from the pool and replaced it with a new disk. The raid has become degraded.
3. After adding a new /dev/sde disk to the pool, I got the following configuration:

```sh
 zpool status
  pool: rpool
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices could not be used because the label is missing or
        invalid.  Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue
        functioning in a degraded state.
action: Replace the device using 'zpool replace'.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-4J
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 0h25m with 0 errors on Wed Sep  2 18:32:39 2020
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        rpool       DEGRADED     0     0     0
          mirror-0  DEGRADED     0     0     0
            old     UNAVAIL      0     0     0
            sdf2    ONLINE       0     0     0
          sde2      ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Replacing, offline, deleting "old" always get an error:

```sh
zpool replace rpool old

cannot open 'old': no such device in /dev

must be a full path or shorthand device name
```

In file /etc/zfs/zpool.cache I see drive /dev/sde2/old

How do I remove the old disk without restarting the server and deleting the array (the array is /)?

---

```
root@v05:/# zpool replace rpool old sde2
invalid vdev specification
use '-f' to override the following errors:
/dev/sde2 is part of active pool 'rpool'

root@v05:/# zpool replace -f rpool old sde2
invalid vdev specification
the following errors must be manually repaired:
/dev/sde2 is part of active pool 'rpool'
```

sde already rpool member.

Need remove old (/dev/sde/old) disk from pool.

No error when adding the new disk, did everything exactly as you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

You probably did an error when adding the new disk: you issued `zpool add rpool <newdisk>`, but you had to **replace** the failed disk. In other words, you had to either:

- `zpool replace rpool <olddisk> <newdisk>`
- `zpool detach rpool <olddisk>; zpool attach rpool sdf` (`sdf` being the other mirror leg).

Notice how I wrote `attach`, while you probably used `add` in your zpool command.

How can you fix the issue? With ZFS 0.7.x you are out of luck, as no data vdev can be removed after being added. With **ZFS 0.8.x you can remove it** so, if you are running ZFS 0.7.x, you need to update to 0.8.x as first step. Then you must issue the above command to replace the failed disk.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.

zdb

find identification 15497986214547762579 for /dev/sde/old device and remove:

zpool offline -f rpool 15497986214547762579

zpool detach rpool 15497986214547762579

Answer (score 0):

I made a disk replacement according to the oracle documentation. I now have the following command output:

root@v05:/# zpool replace rpool old sde2
invalid vdev specification
use '-f' to override the following errors:
/dev/sde2 is part of active pool 'rpool'

root@v05:/# zpool replace -f rpool old sde2
invalid vdev specification
the following errors must be manually repaired:
/dev/sde2 is part of active pool 'rpool'